# What do I need to change for Google+ APIs and OAuth shutdown?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, passport.js, google-plus

I received an email from Google which has this content:

> Hello Google+ Developer,
>
> The email below contains your most recent usage of Google+ APIs. Note: It includes Google+ OAuth scope requests, which are also affected by the Google+ shutdown. A prior email sent to active API callers did not include information about OAuth requests. One final reminder email will be sent in February to users who still have active API or OAuth request activity.
>
> ### What do I need to know?
>
> On March 7, 2019, all Google+ APIs and Google+ Sign-in will be shut down completely. This will be a progressive shutdown, with API calls starting to intermittently fail as early as January 28, 2019, and OAuth requests for Google+ scopes starting to intermittently fail as early as February 15, 2019.
>
> ### What do I need to do?
>
> Please update your projects listed below by March 7, 2019 and ensure they are no longer using Google+ APIs, or requesting Google+ OAuth scopes. The data below shows which Google+ API methods your projects have recently called, as well as Google+ OAuth scopes it has requested.
>
> Note: If you see calls to people.get, these can be the result of using the Google+ Sign-In feature in your application, which is now fully deprecated and is being shut down. Developers should migrate from the Google+ Sign-In feature to the more comprehensive Google Sign-in authentication system.

```
| Project   | Google+ API Name  | Version | Method or OAuth ScopeA |   
|   A       | plus              | v1      | plus.people.get        |
|   B       | plus              | v1      | plus.people.get        |
```

I'm using passport and this [plugin for google](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-google-oauth) to avoid storing a password for the users. But I also need the email address. I tried to use just the `email` scope, but that didn't work, so that's why I'm using both scopes. Here is a snippet, how I used it:

I request two scopes, here is the snippet for it:

```
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;

const app = exprress();
auth(passport);
app.use(passport.initialize());
const auth = function (passport) = {
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
        done(null, user);
    });
    passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
        done(null, user);
    });
    passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
            clientID: CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
            callbackURL: CALLBACK_URL
        },
        (token, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
            return done(null, {
                profile: profile,
                token: token
            });
        }));
};
app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ['profile', 'email']
}));
```

So now I'm confused a bit, because I don't use `plus.people.get` scope.
And even on this [documentation page](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/Scopes) they recommend to use `profile` and `email`. So why I'm getting the email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue isn't that you use the `plus.profile` *scope*, it is that the library uses the HTTP *endpoint* for `plus.people.get` to get the profile information. Even if you're not using a `plus` scope, best practice three years ago was to use the plus endpoints to get profile information.

There is a [pull request](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth2/pull/51) that changes the endpoint that is used. It isn't clear to me why it hasn't been merged, but it should be shortly.

In the meantime, you can also specify the endpoint in the `userProfileURL` property for the configuration when you create the `GoogleStrategy` object. So that code could look something like

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: CALLBACK_URL,
        userProfileURL: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo'
    },
    (token, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        return done(null, {
            profile: profile,
            token: token
        });
    }));
```

There is also [another module](https://github.com/panva/node-openid-client) which uses OpenID (which Google supports) to get the profile information. You may wish to switch to this one, since it appears to be supported.